# Build of Win_Ros with Visual Studio 2013 for Kinect2 usage

Tags: windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am going to use a Kinect 2 sensor with ROS. As for now Kinect 2 SDK is available on Windows 8, I thought on using ROS for windows to send some data to an Ubuntu computer which will use it. But right now, the win_ros package is built with visual studio 2010 and the Windows7 sdk. Looking around I have seen more people interested in the use of the Kinect 2 sensor, also thinking on the "Windows sending the Kinect data to Linux" solution, but I suppose that if it was done directly with ROS, this would simplify a lot of things.

I would like to ask if there is anyone who has the knowledge and may be interested in making a built to be used with the new versions of VS.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188820/build-of-win_ros-with-visual-studio-2013-for-kinect2-usage/) by [gcc05](https://answers.ros.org/users/19929/gcc05/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tinytron](https://answers.ros.org/users/20467/tinytron/) on 2014-11-27**:
Did you see this? https://github.com/personalrobotics/k2_server/wiki/Integrating-Kinect-for-windows-v2-with-ROS

**Comment by [gcc05](https://answers.ros.org/users/19929/gcc05/) on 2014-11-27**:
This one looks interesting, even though it looks quite similar to the rosserial-windows as suggested in the comment of tonybaltovski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Clearpath used `rosserial_windows`  with the Kinect 2.0.  [Link](http://hackaday.com/2014/07/21/cutting-ribbons-with-robots-and-a-oculus-rift/)

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now, yours is a slightly fresher approach to the problem; So far I haven't seen anyone discussing Kinect2 on  Windows with ROS.

You will see this answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/187283/using-a-xbox-one-kinect-on-a-turtlebot/post-id-187364%3C/p%3E) , from @BennyRe, stating that, indeed, there is no current support for Kinect2 on ROS, that some people is indeed capturing data on Windows and using on Linux, but all on Windows... As I said, nobody really discussed for a while.

The limitation seems to be on OpenNI, which usually handles Kinect data; They still haven't figured out how to make it "talk" to ROS. Protocol. So, my educated guess would be that THIS needs to be developed, platform-independent. Not quite sure if this is what you are proposing though.

---

Originally posted by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) with karma: 255 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gcc05](https://answers.ros.org/users/19929/gcc05/) on 2014-08-04**:
I have not much experience in using Kinect and ROS either, but what I was thinking about was making a Windows ROS node which used the Kinect 2 SDK (the one from Microsoft), and sent the data via some ros topic to the Linux computer.